# Binary Palindrome

Tags: algorithms, palindrome

Let an integer n be given. Write the integers from 1 to n in binary notation successively from left to right. In the resulting string consisting of zeros and ones, choose a palindrome substring of maximal length. It is required to find the length of this substring. For example, if n=5, we can get a string which is 1 10 11 100 101. And we can get the longest substring that is palindromic: 11011 or 01110. So the answer to the question is 5. The n can be very big. Are there any good algorithm to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try "usual" palindrome algorithms? Like  [http://www.akalin.cx/longest-palindrome-linear-time]

Comment: I think it need some special properties to solve it. Since n can be 2^1000000, it is too large to deal with in normal ways.

Comment: I'm wondering if you actually need an algorithm as such. There are regularities. The best I've found is a string of length $3n+1$, in the sequence $2^n+5, 2^n+6, 2^n+7$.

$$...0, \; \{1\;\underbrace{000...0}_\text{n-3 times}\; 101, \; 1\;\underbrace{000...0}_\text{n-3 times}\; 110, 1\;\underbrace{000...0}_\text{n-3 times}\; 1\}11, ...$$

Comment: I find the same as Neil up to $2^{19}$. It would be interesting to prove such a result